# User Input of Date as a Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a query which goes like this:

```
StockAnalytics.uDIX - StockAnalytics.dDIX > 0.5 
    AND (Today1.uDIX - Today1.dDix) > 0.5 
    AND (Today2.uDIX - Today2.dDix) > 0.5 
    AND (Today1.uDIX - Today1.dDix) > (Today2.uDIX - Today2.dDIX)
    AND (Today2.uDIX - Today2.dDIX) > (Today3.uDIX - Today3.dDIX) 
    AND StockAnalytics.[Date] > @Date
```

I am trying to take the input from the user on which date he wants to run the query. When I enter the date, it asks for the same input twice.

Anything wrong with this query?

Soham

**EDIT**: I don't think, I could get my problem across. When I use this code snippet, it works perfectly, except for the fact that, the dialog box, prompting the user to enter the Date, *comes twice* I don't want to have it pop twice. Only after the user has entered the "date" the second time, does the results come up

Comment: What asks twice?  Is it matching multiple records?  Run the query in a command window yourself.

Comment: That is the dialog box asking for Date is coming twice. I have been running this in the window and its running, yet I have to enter the same date twice before I see any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to include a parameter twice as in:

```
 SELECT Stuff
 FROM ATable
 WHERE FirstDate > [Please enter date: ]
 AND SecondDate > [Please enter date: ]
```

Then include a parameter line:

```
 PARAMETERS [Please enter date: ] DateTime;
 SELECT Stuff
 FROM ATable
 WHERE FirstDate > [Please enter date: ]
 AND SecondDate > [Please enter date: ]
```

Or better yet, use a form:

```
 SELECT Stuff
 FROM ATable
 WHERE FirstDate > Forms!Dates!txtDate
 AND SecondDate > Forms!Dates!txtDate
```

Comment: thanks but I am not looking for a functionality change. I added a clarification to the opening post.

Comment: @Soham I am afraid your OP is not at all clear to me. Is the same date used twice? Do you wish the user to enter a date at all? Have you misspelled anything? What should be happening?

Comment: When you use a form, you should declare the form reference as a parameter, too. Otherwise, you can have unreliable results (particularly with Nulls).